# Can you help me identify this set? (Emergency vehicles maybe?)

Tags: set-identification, instructions, city

Bags are numbered 1-3. It looks like it maybe is some sort of emergency vehicle set? Bag 3 looks like a fire truck and bag 1 maybe a police car?

Thank you!

[image: lego sets 1-3]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like *Set# [60060-1 Auto Transporter](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=60060-1).*

[image]